# How can I change out the LXDE panel/menu for a better one?

Tags: menu, lxde

I changed out Unity for LXDE because this old desktop just couldn't handle the load well. The problem is that the menu is plain and somewhat difficult to work with. Is there a way to replace it with something a little more user friendly? Specifically, I know some distros have a search box in the LXDE menu. What are my options?

Thanks!

Comment: I want to replace my LXDE menu with something better. Are there any other options out there?

Comment: VTC because "better" is opinion-based.

Comment: This may or may not be what you're looking for but you might want to check out the XFCE desktop as an alternative. It's at least something to consider...

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to install the Whisker menu. This is part of Xubuntu but if you install it, you'll have the necessary dependencies pulled in. Then, you'll need to use the xfce4 panel instead of the lxde one. In my opinion, there shouldn't be much of an additional burden. To install the Whisker menu, run this:

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin xfce4-panel
```

There's a [video on Xubuntu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lOOAfwmmOeQ) which shows you a bit about the Whisker menu to help you decide.

And the developer's blog is here: [Whisker Menu 1.3.0 released!](https://gottcode.wordpress.com/category/open-source/whisker-menu/)